# No network connection functionality issue on IOS using IONIC

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am working on my No Connection functionality (my app must be connected to work).  I detect the Network Connection and redirect to a page with a retry button and nice message. This works great on Android but not on iOS9

```
if (window.Connection) {
     $rootScope.currentState = $state.current.name;
     if (navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE) {
         $state.go('internet-error');
     } else{
         $state.go('login');
     }
 }
```

Try to give some solution is that any changes require on config.xml

Answer (score 1):

First you need to install cordova-plugin-network-information **[plugin](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins)**

***https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information***

then add following code

```
.run(function($rootScope, $location, $state, $ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {        
        $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function(event, next, current)    {      
            if (window.Connection) {
                if (navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE) {
                    $state.go('internet-error');
                }else{
                    $state.go('login');
                }
             }
        }); 
    });     
})
```